# Get the selected item from an html.listboxfor without doing a post in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I am starting up on MVC, but this is what I want.

I have a list of items on one side and a text box on the other. I want to click on an item from the list and have the text box show that item's text, but not with the use of a button or post; something similar to a "`OnSelectedIndexChanged`".

This is what I have so far.

CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new TestModel();
    model.ListOfItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
    item.Text = "Item's text";
    item.Value = "Value for the list";
    model.ListOfItems.Add(item);
    return View(model);
}
```

MODEL:

```
public int[] ItemId { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> ListOfItems { get; set; }
```

VIEW:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showText() {
    var selectedItem = itemsList.options.selectedIndex;
    txtValue.Text = selectedItem.value;
}
</script>
<h2>Test</h2>

@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.ItemId, new MultiSelectList(Model.ListOfItems, "Text", "Value", Model.ItemId), new { size = 6, id = "itemsList", OnChange = "showText" })
@Html.TextBox("itemText", "", new { id = "txtItem" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have some javascript which listens to the click event on the listbox and get the item text and set as the value of the other textbox

```
$(function(){

  $("#ItemId option").click(function () {
    var _this = $(this);
    $("#txtItem").val($(_this).text());
  });

});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/w4sxw/

Assuming you have jQuery loaded to the page.

Comment: The code works half way. If you see the jsfiddle sample the list is something like this: <option value="22">Another omn</option>
<option value="3">Customer Complaint</option>. What I want to show on the text box is the "value" of each option/item (like the 22 and the 3) not the text. If I change the script from .text to .value it doesn't work.

Comment: Got it!    $("#txtValue").val($(_this).val());   THANKS!